Clear overgrown area beneath plants and trees
What's the easiest way to kill and clear grass and dandelion, plus a few other weeds, that have crept under trees and bushes, from my lawn?
Photo attached, and given back troubles I'm trying to make this as lightweight a job as possible...



An herbicide is the wrong way to go as it could also kill the shrub or adjacent plants.

Edge the area you want cleared with a spade
Use a turf lifter or flat edge spade to lift up the grass and the soil attached to it
Rake over the cleared area to remove any roots or debris
top with at least one inch of a mulch of your choice

Job done and it should not take more than an hour!

Hand weed what you can. Spot treat what's left with Roundup. If hand weeding is too much trouble, just treat everything with Roundup. Follow Roundup instructions to the letter. Chose a calm, dry day. Remember that Roundup is absorbed through the leaves and cannot distinguish between plants you want to keep and plants you want to kill.

Especially after hand weeding, is glyphosate really needed here, inside a tree's drip line?
